# Swift Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap, forced-unwrapping

I am getting this problem in my code:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This message appears on this line of my code:

```
try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileLocation!))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if event?.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.motionShake {

            let fileLocation = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")

            do {
                try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileLocation!))
                player.play()
            } catch {
                // process error   
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is basically telling you that `fileLocation` is `nil` when it shouldn't.

Comment: ok thanks! So how can I fix this?

Comment: @grooveplex did I do something wrong?

Comment: You need to assure that `fileLocation` is not `nil`, which probably means making sure the file you're trying to load exists — I can't help you much more, because I'm not very experienced with swift yet 

Comment: @grooveplex ok thanks anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0):

Your file wasn't found.

I made some minor changes to aid debugging and prevent crashing.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if event?.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.motionShake {
            if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3") {
                do {
                    let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileLocation))
                    player.play()
                } catch (_) {
                    print("AVAudioPlayer could not play the file.")
                }
            } else {
                print("File was not be found.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tired the code but It keeps saying "File was not be found."

Comment: Where is sound1.mp3 located? I placed it in the root directory of the project and it worked for me!

Comment: hey I put it in the root folder but inside another folder called “sounds”

Comment: Have you tried prepending the folder name? `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sounds/sound1", ofType: "mp3")`

Comment: I’ve tired that too multiple times but not having any luck

Comment: I think you need to use func `url(forResource:wihExtension:subdirectory:)` on Bundle.main [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1416712-url) You can then pass "sounds" as the subdirectory.